# How to specify pixel resolution when converting feature collection to image in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, rasterization

I have a feature collection and I would like to convert it into a raster image. I would like the resulting image to have 30m spatial resolution. 
How can I use the `reduceToImage` method to assign resolution when saving the resulting image as an asset?

Here's my script:

```js
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/mattelearning85/exe/2009_shapefile");
print(table)
var table_raster = table.reduceToImage(['Area_ha'], 'mean');
print(table_raster)
```

[Code Editor link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/24b4ce289e6eaed33e786d05d747b239)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `Export.image.toAsset()` you can specify scale using the `scale` parameter.